# "Inverse Resolution" of a model of a countably categorical theory

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$ be a countably categorical first order theory. Let $M \vDash T$ be arbitrary and countable.

Show that there exists $\{M_n : n \in \omega \}$ of countable models of $T$ such that $M_{n+1} \prec M_n$ ($M_{n+1}$ is a *proper* elementary substructure of $M_n$), and $M = \cap_{n < \omega}M_n$.

I don't think it's as simple as doing a bunch of Downwards Lowenheim Skolem. I was thinking of defining a model $B = (N, P_i)_{i \in \omega}$ where each predicate will eventually be interpreted as $M_i$ and say that, for every formula $\phi$, $B$ is a model of $P_{i+1}(a) \implies (\phi(a)^{P_{i+1}} \iff \phi(a)^{P_i})$ where the superscript indicates the relativization of the formula. $B$ will also model other sentences indicating $P_{i+1} \subset P_i$ and the $P_i$ are models, etc. But I'm not sure how to fill the details. I don't think $\cap P_i^B = M$ is necessarily true either.

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: If each of the $M_n$s is countable, then $M$ itself had better be countable.

Comment: Yes $M$ is countable of course I forgot to write that.

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate. Note that the theorem is true for *any* countable theory $T$, not just countably categorical ones.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to comment once a question has been closed but I have a few questions after looking at the linked solutions. Am I wrong in saying that thanks to $\aleph_0$ categoricity, my indiscernible sequence will automatically be coheir? Finally, I don't quite see why a coheir sequence removes the possibility of $M \subsetneq \cap M_i$ (This is my first time hearing of the concept).